# Introspect attributes used by a method

Tags: python, introspection

I'd like to know if it is possible to retrieve attributes used by a method.

Here is a sample to explain what I am trying to do:

```
class Foobar(object):

    bar = 123

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return self.baz * self.bar

    def get_foobar(self):
        return '{} * {} = {}'.format(self.baz, self.bar, self.foo)
```

I would like to be able to know that calling `Foobar().get_foobar()` will require `self.baz`, `self.bar` and `self.foo` to be set, without actually calling it.

My current approach is to add an attribute to `get_foobar`:

```
def get_foobar(self):
    return '{} * {} = {}'.format(self.baz, self.bar, self.foo)
get_foobar.requires = ['baz', 'bar', 'foo']
```

However, I think it is a bit redundant and might be error-prone.

---

#### What is the point of doing this?

You may wonder why I'd like to achieve this behavior.

In my concrete case, `Foobar` is actually a django model. And attributes are actually fields retrieve from the database. I created a [`View` mixin](https://github.com/apinsard/khango/blob/db0db05/khango/views/behaviors.py#L102-L149) that enables me to specify the fields needed by the view. For instance:

```
class SomeUserView(ModelMixin, View):
    model = User
    fields = [
        'username', 'groups__name', 'permissions__id',
        'orders__products__name', 'orders__products__price',
    ]
```

With a few introspection, I can build the query that will retrieve all and only the data needed by the view. In this case, it would look like:

```
User.objects.all().only(
    'username', 'groups__name', 'permissions__id',
    'orders__products__name', 'orders__products__price',
).select_related('groups', 'permissions', 'orders__products')
```

Now, the `fields` attribute may contain not only fields, but also instance methods, which may require fields that are not listed. Let's say I have:

```
class User(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return '{} ({})'.format(self.username, self.email)
    __str__.requires_fields = ['username', 'email']

class Permission(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    __str__.requires_fields = ['name']

class SomeUserView(ModelMixin, View):
    model = User
    fields = [
        'username', 'groups__name', 'permissions', '__str__',
        'orders__products__name', 'orders__products__price',
    ]
```

Then, the query will be:

```
User.objects.all().only(
    'username', 'groups__name', 'permissions__name', 'email',
    'orders__products__name', 'orders__products__price',
).select_related('groups', 'permissions', 'orders__products')
```

This works, however I would like to avoid setting the `requires_fields` attribute to each methods and have to update it carefully every time the method is revised.

---

I have no great hope in this being possible, but still asking.

---

As an alternative, I think I could write a decorator, such as:

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, obj, fields):
        self.obj = obj
        self.fields = set(fields)
        self._used_fields = set()

    def __getattribute___(self, name):
        if name not in self.fields:
            raise AttributeError(
                "You forgot to set '{}' as required field".format(name))
        self._used_fields.add(name)
        return getattr(self.obj, name)

    def exit_method(self):
        if self.fields != self._used_fields:
            warnings.warn(
                "Make sure the following fields are actually needed: {}".format(
                    self.fields - self._used_fields))

def requires_fields(*fields):
    def decorator(func):
        def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self_wrapper = Wrapper(self, fields)
            func(self_wrapper, *args, **kwargs)
            self_wrapper.exit_method()
        inner.__name__ = func.__name__
        inner.requires_fields = fields
    return decorator

@requires_fields('baz', 'bar', 'foo')
def get_foobar(self):
   return '{} * {} = {}'.format(self.baz, self.bar, self.foo)
```

So that I can ease "mistakes detection". But it looks quite odd. :D

Comment: Does the `inspect` module help?

Comment: @hpaulj `inspect` looks interesting. I think I can do something with `inspect.getsource` and `ast`.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to be able to know that calling Foobar().get_foobar()
>   will require self.baz, self.bar and self.foo to be set, without
>   actually calling it.

No, of course not, in the general case. Here's *my* foobar:

```
return self.foo if isHalting() else self.bar
return eval("self.foo")
```

But more realistically, you have several options:

1. Compile [the syntax tree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html). Check for the field nodes (or whichever you're interested in) then see what their value is. This can be time consuming. Familiarize yourself with the visitor pattern and this can be a pretty powerful way to parse; this is how a static language like C or Java could raise a compilation error that a variable will be undefined*.
2. Check for closures with `function.get.__closure__` This won't help you retrieve all the fields, but may help you figure out which fields have been bound to the function, which may be relevant in some cases
3. The best option, is to use try/except statements. Style them however you want, but for example

   `def foo():
        s = ''
        try:
           s += str(self.baz)
        except: raise NoBazError("No Baz!")`

   To me, this is the best option because it's the most explicit and straightforward.

---

`*` That would be tough for even a statically typed language if you're using fields, but local variables can be checked for initialization, sometimes